# Can you calculate the mean of a multivariate normal distribution for the cosine similarity?

Tags: probability, distributions, cosine-similarity

Let ${\displaystyle \mathbf {X} =(X_{1},\ldots ,X_{k})^{\mathrm {T} }}$ be a sample from  a multivariate normal distribution ${\displaystyle \mathbf {X} \ \sim \ {\mathcal {N}}({\boldsymbol {\mu }},\,{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }})}$.

Can you calculate the **mean** of the output distribution after transforming with the following formula (which is the cosine similarity in vector space), assuming that ${\displaystyle \mathbf {w}}=(w_{1},\ldots ,w_{k})^{\mathrm {T} }$ is a fixed vector?
$$
f(\mathbf{X}) = 
\frac
{\sum_{i}{X_{i} w_i}}
{\sqrt{\sum_i{X_i}^2}\sqrt{\sum_i{w_i}^2}}
$$

Comment: It helps to simplify questions like these.  For instance, a suitable invertible linear transformation will map $w$ to $(1,0,\ldots, 0)$ while changing the parameters of $X$ in a definite way, giving another multivariate Normal distribution.  This simplifies the function to $f(X)=X_1/\sqrt{X_1^2+\cdots+X_k^2}.$  Now you can apply another invertible linear transformation to $X,$ reducing the function to $f(X)=X_1/\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}.$

Comment: Is calculating $E[f(\mathbf{X})]$ your question?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for pointing this out! I suppose my follow up question is how to calculate the mean of the resulting function then?

Comment: @Zhanxiong yes, by calculation of the mean I meant the expectation [()]

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer quite intuitive. Consider the sketch below. As cosine similarity deals with the angle between $\bf{X}$ and $\bf{w}$, the question boils down to projecting $\bf{X}$ on a sphere passing through the center of the distribution of $\bf{X}$, that is, through $E[\bf{X}]$.
From the symmetry of the distribution of $\bf{X}$, the mean of the projected $\bf{X}$ is on the chord between $E[\bf{X}]$ and the origin.
Therefore, your answer is the cosine similarity between $\bf{w}$ and $E[\bf{X}]$.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail about "the symmetry of the distribution"?  I don't believe this argument works, because that distribution (along with the fixed vector $w$) does not necessarily share the same similarities as the unit sphere.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could please explain what similarities is in the context of the symmetry of a multivariate normal distribution about its mean.

Comment: The information in the problem consists of the matrix $\Sigma,$ which describes a collection of concentric ellipsoids oriented in its (arbitrary) eigendirections; the (arbitrary) mean $\mu,$ and the (arbitrary) vector $w.$  Anything deserving of the term "symmetry" would be a transformation of these data that preserve some property of interest, which here is the cosine similarity.  I am simply asking you to describe the symmetry to which you appeal in this post.  I cannot find any in general.

Comment: Not sure that i understand your comment, but "a multivariate normal distribution" is spherical symmetric about its mean point.
If you want to ask about the symmetry on the sphere, you may, for example, consider an infinitesimal thick sphere on which p(X) is constant, and consider the intersection between this sphere and  the sphere passing through the center of the distribution of X. 
Please also consider this: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038847/is-the-intersection-between-two-n-spheres-an-n-1-sphere)

Comment: Your point of departure is incorrect: $\Sigma$ is not necessarily spherical.   The only symmetries a general multivariate Normal distribution enjoys are those generated by the reflections through the mean $\mu$ determined by the (generically) distinct eigendirections.

Comment: Correct. You are right about the distribution not being spherical. My bad. Yet, there is as symmetry which justifies the answer. The explanation is more complex though. Can you help?

Comment: I can't help, because I believe your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposition and discussion! I may be able to help out: I forgot to mention that ${\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}$ is diagonal, i.e. we assume independence of $X_i$.